# I am trying to understand what {$scope:scope} in ctrl=$controller('TestingAngularControl',{$scope:scope}); is?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

```
 describe('Testing Angular JS Test Suite', function() {

  //before each test, use this module
 beforeEach(module('Testing'));

 describe('Test Controller', function() {
//just think what should the controller do
//used to inject angular components into test
var scope,ctrl;
//creates an isolate scope
scope={};
beforeEach(function(){
  inject(function($controller,$rootScope){
    //$rootScope.$new creates a new instance of $rootScope.Scope that inherits from $rootScope.
    //In other words, it creates a new child scope of $rootScope.
    //new child scope of $rootScope
    //alternative is to use $rootScope itself.
    //Doing so might create a mess since it might be used all over the place

      //assign ctrl to angular controller
      //if an object is placed in the scope then it returns the scope
      //like saying
      /*
      $scope {
        title:''
      }
      put in an object and it gives back the isolate scope
      */
      //passing in an isolate scope, and it returns the scope
      ctrl=$controller('TestingAngularControl',{$scope:scope});
      console.log(ctrl);


  });
});
afterEach(function(){
    //cleanup code goes here
});

it('should initialize the title in the scope', function() {
  //this is from angular-mocks and it include the module we created in our app
  //the value to check with the value to check against
  expect(scope.title).toBeDefined();
  expect(scope.title).toBe('Testing Angular Controller');
   });
 });
 });
```

The comments are just me trying to figure out what scope is doing when its passed in as an object. I am assuming that the object passes in a emtpy object and angularjs returns an isolated scope from the rootScope from this? I just want to make sure my understanding is correct. This is angularjs, I know its outdated, but still interested.

Comment: I have already looked on stackoverflow and have not found suitable explanations yet.

Comment: See [AngularJS $controller Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller).

Comment: that was the first place I looked...have you even looked? The description is nonexistent for this issue

Comment: It explains perfectly what it does. In your case it injects the object named `scope` into the controller as `$scope`. In your code you set `scope` to an empty object, i.e. `{ }`. Maybe you should also read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Depedency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) or [AngularJS $injector Service API Reference - instantiate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector#instantiate).